# How to create a plot of acoustically tagged individuals to show presence of individuals per day

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I am trying to create a plot like the one below. The plot represents a timeline of the daily detections of different acoustically tagged individuals (represented by Transmitter ID). The black dots represent the days when the individual was detected on a receiver, grey bars represent total time at liberty.

I am trying to find out what this type of plot is called, what package I can use and if there is any specific code to make it.

[image]

Comment: This plot can be understood (and plotted) as an _overlay statterplot_ of two scatterplots in the same axes: one is the plack points data, the other is the grey bands data. Each "band" is in fact the start and end positions of a vector (a sort of scatterplot called _start-end vector plot_).

Comment: ...a start-end vector plot, in turn, is the overlay scatterplot of start points scatterplot and end points scatterplot, with the paired points connected by arrow or line. Thus, you have three overlay scatters in all.

Comment: This plot is readily and compactly described using the [Grammar of Graphics](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387245447), so any implementation of GG ought to work well.  One thing to consider is whether the sequence of transmitter identifiers is meaningful.  If not, then vertically reordering the rows by one of the variables (such as length of bands, start, end, or even number of detections) will produce a more information-rich graphic (without any increase in effort beyond the sorting step) and thereby might offer unexpected insight.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. And thank you @whuber, the book looks very interesting and useful, however I was hoping to get some help without having to purchase a book.

Comment: If this is the last statistical graphic you ever plan to create, it likely would be overkill to learn about describing and making good graphics.  But if it's an element of the work you plan to do during a career or lifetime, it's never too early to start learning how to do that work better and more efficiently.